# Using Regexp::Common to get matched parenthesis, without the parenthesis

Tags: regex, perl

This is a minorish point, but I worry I'm doing silly stuff.  I am using Regexp::Common to match a matched-parentheses regular-expression, but I need the *contents* of the parenthesis, not the whole expression.  So I wind up storing a temporary string, performing a post-match replacement on that string to get rid of the parens, and the moving on.  So imagine I'm running the following script on the line "sphincter(arg1,arg2)"  (I'm freehanding a minimal example, so I hope it's understandable).

```
 use Regexp::Common;
 $PAREN_EXP = $RE{balanced}{-parens=>'()'};
 $line =~ /foo$PAREN_EXP/; 
 $temp = $1;  temp now stores (arg1,arg2)
 $temp =~ s/\((.*)\)/$1/; # temp is now arg1,arg2
 $line =~/(.*)\($temp\)/close\($1,$temp\)/;
```

with the result that line is now "close(sphinter, arg1, arg2)", plus or minus whatever errors I made doing the example.  Now this works okay for me, but I have do it pretty often and I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way?    Is there a way to get the Regexp::Common library to just give me the contents?  Is there a way for me to define $PAREN_EXP so that it gives me what I like?  Does someone see a better way?

By better I mean smaller without becoming Write Only Code.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Regexp::Common::balanced helps when you can have nested parentheses, but your example only has a single pair: `(arg1,arg2)` If your data doesn't contain nested parentheses, I would just do this with a single substitution, e.g.: `s/ (.*) \( (.*) \) /close($1,$2)/x`. You can use the `x` modifier to ignore spaces on the LHS, which allows you to space things out to be more readable, or even split them up into multiple lines and add comments. You could also use named captures to clarify what each capture group does, e.g. `s/ (?<func> .*) \( (?<args> .*) \) /close($+{func},$+{args})/x;`

Comment: My example is just the simplest case I could come up with to illustrate my problem.    I took it as obvious that I'm only interested in doing this in cases where it make sense to do so.  Clearly that's not the case.   I am replacing complicated c++ expressions, like foo ( several-argument-often-with-nested-parens-of-arbitrary-depth ), and what I'm doing solves that problem -- I could also write a recursive parse or recursive regexp, but this has proven most expedient so far.

Comment: @Spacemoose Please [edit] your question to include an example of the input you're actually working with and the expected output.

Comment: @ThisSuitsBlackNot:  Yeah I probably won't -- why don't you consider the question from a different point of view:  Perl has a module that I find super useful in a lot of circumstances.  I would find it even better if I could use slightly differently that the quite sparse documentation proviedes, and I'm wondering if anyone out there knows how to do what I would like to do.  For those that don't, don't worry about it, this question is not targeted at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `Regexp::Common::balanced`, because the regex it generates only contains one capturing group, which encloses the outermost set of parentheses:

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common=balanced -E 'say $RE{balanced}{-parens=>"()"}'
(?^:((?:\((?:(?>[^\(\)]+)|(?-1))*\))))
    ^                               ^
    |                               |
    +-------------HERE--------------+
```

Fortunately, `Regexp::Common` lets you [define your own regexes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common#Adding-new-regular-expressions) so you can use the handy `$RE{foo}` syntax:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Regexp::Common qw(pattern);

pattern name   => [qw(inside_parens)],
        create => q/(?x: ( \( ( (?: (?> [^()]+ ) | (?-2) )* ) \) ) )/
        ;

say $2 if 'foo(bar(baz,bat), qux())' =~ /foo$RE{inside_parens}/;
```

#### Output:

```
bar(baz,bat), qux()
```

The entire parenthetical expression is stored in `$1`, while the contents of the parentheses are stored in `$2`.

This regex is a slightly-modified version of the one described in `perldoc perlre` for [matching balanced parentheses](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f_PARNO_%29-%28%3f-_PARNO_%29-%28%3f%2b_PARNO_%29-%28%3fR%29-%28%3f0%29).

Comment: I want to say thanks, even though the input box tells me that this isn't the right place to do that.